# Divide two numbers from two tuples in a bag

Tags: apache-pig

Sorry about the awkward title. What I am trying to do here is for a relation such as:

```
{group: chararray,G: {(query: chararray,type: chararray,count: long)}}
```

which is a result of a 'group by', each key has at most 2 tuples, differentiated by 'type'. E.g. one example may look like:

```
{group:'abc', G:{('abc', 'A', 10), ('abc', 'B', 20)}
```

Now I'd like for each group, do the math of (count in 'A')/(count in 'B'). I am fairly new to Pig and tried different ways but couldnt make it right. Any suggestion? Some things I tried:

```
I = group G by query;
J = foreach I {
CC=filter G by type=='A';
VV=filter G by type=='B';
--generate group, (float)(FLATTEN(CC.count))/(float)(FLATTEN(VV.count)) as CTR, CC, VV ;
--or generate group, (float)(FLATTEN(CC.count))/FLATTEN(VV.count), CC.count, VV.count;
--or generate group, CC.count/VV.count, CC.count, VV.count;
```

}

None worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you have preconditions on your data, like "each key has at most 2 tuples", then I'd recommend not using `GROUP`, which is not designed to handle what you have in mind.  Instead, you can `SPLIT` your dataset in two and then `JOIN` the pieces back together.  This way you can keep each key's tuples straight.  For example:

```
SPLIT G INTO typeA IF type == 'A', typeB IF type == 'B';
I = JOIN typeA BY query, typeB BY query;
J = FOREACH I GENERATE typeA::query, (float)typeA::count/typeB::count;
```